# Dimension of $Range(A)$ and $Range(A^2)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Which of the following matrices satisfies the property "Dimension of $Range(A)$ and $Range(A^2)$ is 2 and 1 respectively."

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$ B=\begin{bmatrix}
0 &0& 1& 0\\
0 &0& 1& 0\\
0 &0 &0 &1\\
0 &0& 0 &1\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Now the columns represent the coefficients of the images of the basis elements. After a lot of consideration I am convinced (by observation) that both $A$ and $B$ satisfy the above property. But only one can be the right answer, I am confused. Help please!

Comment: Have you computed both $A^{2}$ and $B^{2}$?  How many non-zero columns do they have?

Comment: I'm sorry, but both are right answers, if my computations are exact.

Comment: @JohnMcGee Yup I did that too. The row rank of $A^2$, $B^2$ and $A$ ,$B$ all check out!

Comment: @Bernard I am convinced of that too. In fact it is quite a trivial matter. However this was a national exam. I don't know how they can get it wrong!

Comment: Why only one is answer? While both have 2 and 1 with the required property ?

Comment: They everytime make mistakes in there question and options

Answer (score 1):

No real need to compute $B^2$.

Clearly both matrices have ranges equal to $2$.

Clearly also, $A^2$ and $B^2$ apply the first $3$ vectors of the canonical basis to $0$. While $Ae_4$ and $Be_4$ Are not vanishing. Hence both matrices have the required property.

Comment: You should note the rank nullity theorem the range of one vector cannot be a dimension more than 1

Comment: A non zero vector always generates a vector subspace of dimension one!

Comment: You are right. But A had the same property.